# Visual Studio 2013 and Deploying Typescript Html Template

Tags: visual-studio, azure, typescript

Since WebEssensial removed its typescript support and we started to use the visual studio plugin from typescriptlang a few changes have happened.

Now the javascript files are not getting added as a part of the project. This is nice as they dont fill up in the solution explorer.

This also means when deploying the site (i was deploying to windows azure websites), the javascript files are not deployed.

What are people doing to get around this?

Is there a way to either collapse included javascript/typescript files under eachother with a + sign like webessensial did.

or to tell visual studio it should include all javascript files when publishing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get around the problem by including the .js files in my project. Next, I select both files, right click on them, and select "Group Items". The Group Items feature lets you select the parent item and then groups them together. I don't know if the "Group Items" feature is built-in or comes with a plugin though. If you don't have that feature, I can probably figure out which plugin does that.

Comment: but searching for group files is a good idea :)  <Compile Include="FileA.cs"/>
<Compile Include="FileA.xml">
  <DependentUpon>FileA.cs</DependentUpon>
</Compile>

Comment: I think the plugin that does it is called VSCommands.. .http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c6d1c265-7007-405c-a68b-5606af238ece